# Select only First UL Li in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a html code

```
<ul id="menu1">
 <li> //When Click this will fire Jquery event
   <a href="">Some word</a>
     <ul style="display:block;">
         <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> //When Click this will fire Jquery event
   <a href="">Some word</a>
     <ul style="display:block;">
         <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> //When Click this will fire Jquery event
   <a href="">Some word</a>
     <ul style="display:block;">
         <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My Question is I want to fire my jquery code when i click the main UL LI element , i do not want to fire jquery for the inner UL LI. but some how no matter how i try, it will fire all LI , below is my jquery

```
$('#menu1 li').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

I also try #ul li , #ul li a . but it seems like nothing work. is it anyway to achieve what I need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the child combinator selector (`>`) to only select the top level `li` children of the `#menu1` element. Try this:

```
$('#menu1 > li').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Although note that your code does not match up with the description of what you're trying to achieve. You need to instead place the event handler on the `a` element within the top level `li`, and amend the DOM traversal to find the related `ul` to toggle it. Also note that your HTML is invalid - you're missing the `</li>` tags. Try this:

```js
$('#menu1 > li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu1">
  <li>
    <a href="">Some word</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Some word</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Some word</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem glad to help